# Loop a XML in javascript and get values

Tags: javascript, xml

Im trying to print out the content of an xml string but can't get it to work. Anyone that can see my misstake?

XML string:

```
<row>
    <text>Hello</text>
    <value>1</value>
</row>
<row>
    <text>Hello2</text>
    <value>2</value>
</row>
<row>
    <text>Hello3</text>
    <value>3</value>
</row>
```

The XML is a string that is sent to showXML function.

Javascript:

```
function showXML(xmlText) {
    var ele = document.getElementById("Content");
    ele.style.display = "block";
    var doc = StringtoXML(xmlText); //Coverts string to XML

    var html = "";

    var rows = doc.getElementsByTagName("row");
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {     
        var text = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("text").nodeValue;
        var value= rows[i].getElementsByTagName("value").nodeValue;  
        html = html + " text: " + text + " value: " +value;   
    }  
    ele.innerHTML = html;
} 

function StringtoXML(text){
if (window.ActiveXObject){
    var doc=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.async='false';
    doc.loadXML(text);
} else {
    var parser=new DOMParser();
    var doc=parser.parseFromString(text,'text/xml');
}
return doc;
}
```

Thx for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the correction required in your for loop

```
    var text = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var value= rows[i].getElementsByTagName("value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

getElementsByTagName returns an array/collection.

Comment: [`getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` of all descendant Elements with a given tag name, in document order.](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1938918D)

Comment: Are you using the the code as below:                                   for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {     
                        
        var text = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var value= rows[i].getElementsByTagName("value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;  
        html = html + " text: " + text + " value: " +value;   
}